Tamagui nested components styling
I am new to Tamagui and a bit confused about what is a proper way to style nested components from the outside?
For example if I have a custom Table component with the following hierarchy:
<Table>
     <Row>
        <Cell>Text</Cell>
     </Row>  
</Table>

And I need to set a cell background for some particular table.
Using CSS I could say something like this:
'& .table .row .cell': {background: 'red'}
But how it is supposed to be done with Tamagui?
Any ideas are welcome!
Thanks!
I've tried to pass styles with props or use context or themes, but all of these things require significant code inside the component I need to style.
By other words, I should implement an interface for each component to allow style it from the outside, which is not convenient.
